# How do I get Friendship Tokens?

Tags: zelda-tri-force-heroes

You need Friendship Tokens to craft some of the special tunics in the game.

The game manual says nothing on how to get them.  The in-game people imply that you have to play with "New Friends," which I took to mean playing with "unknown people" on the Internet.

However, even after completing all the stages in World 1 with unknown people, I still have 0 Friendship Tokens.

How do I get Friendship Tokens?

Comment: I think you need to play with people in real life, but I'm not 100% certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [interviews with producers Hiromasa Shikata and Eiji Aonuma](http://gonintendo.com/stories/244489-zelda-tri-force-heroes-mentality-friendship%20-tokens-explained), Frienship tokens are awarded as follows:

When playing using Local multiplayer or Download play, you gain 1 Friendship token for each unique 3DS or New 3DS you play a game with.

From what I've heard, this maxes out at 15 Friendship Tokens, the same amount that the guy next to the castle gate has.

These are used to make the Timeless Tunic (3 tokens) and Tri Suit (5 tokens).

Comment: I'm not sure what the other 7 tokens are used for.  Possibly a suit unlocked later in the game?

Comment: Maybe the rest are just meant to be sold.